# Remote Event Receiver not always executed, yet always received

Tags: sharepoint-online, wcf, remote-event-receiver

We have a SPO site with remote event receivers configured.
About 80% of all events (in this case: ItemAdded) are executed just fine.
About 20% isn't processed. Usually, we can debug the process, but here I'm hitting a wall..

Events that aren't executed:

- Do appear in the IIS logging (returning a 202, instead of a 202 +
  200)
- Do appear in the WCF log tracing (only the request, no response, in consistency with the IIS logging)
- Do appear in the global.asax's Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest (as per custom logging confirmed)
- Never enter the first line of the ProcessEvent method (the other 80% do)
- Never write any entry in the server's event log

Any luminous ideas where my requests have gone, or how to track them?
Is this a common issue with RERs, or can it be handled by a config setting?

Comment: Do the sizes of the payloads sent to your external service exceed a limit set on your service?

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed event receivers that have probably been executed hundreds of thousands of times and have found them to be extraordinarily robust, so you likely have a bug in either your code or your setup.

ItemAdded is an asynchronous event and it should fire the ProcessOneWayEvent method and not the ProcessEvent method. To test this I would implement the ProcessOneWayEvent and drop a breakpoint or a log entry in there just so you can rule that out as a possibility.

**edit** -> One way to check the synchronization of your event receiver would be to run this:

`Get-PnPEventReceiver -List $listName | ft ReceiverName, ReceiverUrl, EventType, Synchronization`

Look for your receiver (it should be the only one with a ReceiverUrl) and note the synchronization type.